# How can I ensure a read-only transaction in SqLite?

Tags: c++, sql, c, sqlite

I have public interface which allows people to interact with the database by typing in sql commands. However, I do not want them to change the database in any way (and if possible, not access certain tables). As I understand though, SQLite has no concept of users, so how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the "master" database file first and open that :-) No, really, this is a serious suggestion.

Otherwise, depending on how SQLite is accessed, the [SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY flag](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) that can be passed to `sqlite3_open_v2`. This applies to the entire connection -- and all transactions on that connection.

Another option is to limit the SQL entry, but this is *very very hard* to do correctly and thus I don't recommend this route.

Happy coding.

Comment: Lol, i cant seriously believe that no one has had this problem before and had to resort to this. This has a lot of problems too, btw. 1. my database is an amalgomation of db files; i use a view which spreads queries out across multiple files 2. it doesnt display data in a live fashion 3.the databases are huge meaning that copying will be slow

Comment: @chacham15 I updated with the open mode bit, not sure if it was in last you saw. Had to update my low-level API knowledge.

Comment: ah ha! beautiful! quick side question: can i have one connection open in read/write and another in read only? also, any way to limit what tables they can read?

Comment: @chacham15 Never tried, honestly. Should be okay -- go for it and report back brave soldier! ;-)

Comment: @chacham15 I know of no such way -- as pointed out, SQLite is sort of lacking in the permission department. Perhaps look into a "full" RDMBS like [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)? It's "zero installation" and I think it supports and embedded mode as well... haven't played with it in years. It's also very Windows-specific these days it looks like.

Answer (score 2):

If within the query there are no application defined `sql` functions, which indirectly modifies the database(e.g: `SELECT eval('DELETE FROM t1') FROM t2;` ), then use `sqlite3_stmt_readonly` to determine whether the prepared `sql` statement writes the database, otherwise you can try to open an other, `read_only`, database connection `handler(SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY)` which will be used for `read_only` access.